# Как настроить отображение фото товара и миниатюры Woocoomerce

Tags: woocommerce, php

Доброго времени суток.

Не скажу что новичек, но гуглить уже порядком надоело.

Задача: на странице (карточка) товара под ФОТО товара вывести миниатюры фото из галереи.

Стандартное решение вукомерца, не удовлятворяет:
при выводе миниатюр, из галереи, "Включить лайтбокс" просто выпихивает в блок фотки. (Внизу топика ссылка на мою карточку товара, я вывел для примера.)

Понимаю, что надо отключить этот скрипт Вуу "Лайтбокс", удалить код и взять нормальный слайдер типа nextgen.

1. В какой файл мне вносить правки - `single-product или content-single-product.php`?
2. Возможно, есть готовая вставка на php?
3. Где найти пример пхп на вставку от некстген?
4. В АДМИНКЕ при создании товара как добавить в правую колонку некстген галерею как функционал, ведь для создания галереи для конкретного товара необходимо выводить определенные фото из общей библиотеки, сейчас использую стандартный функционал.

---

Примитив, что я сделал

В текстовом блоке полное описание товара, вставил шорткод некстгена, который доступен после установки плагина, залил еще раз фото, создал галерею, выбрал галерею - и вуаля, работает. А есть необходимость вставить СЛАЙДЕР миниатюр или даже, возможно, и ВЕРХНЮЮ фото вообще заменить, заменить ВЕСЬ кусок галереи вукомерца на некстген или аналог?

Прошу старожил дать понимание.

http://troica.com.ua/shop/podarki-i-podarochnye-nabory/podarok-novogodnij - 
моя карточка товара, где вы видите 1 картинку и сразу ПОД ФОТО - это ЛАЙТ БОКС, а ниже то, что я хочу туда впихнуть.

Что почитать какие примеры, чтобы добить этот кусок?